Hash CSS Module Styles with Vite
I have a project setup with Nuxt 3 and I am using a css file called grid.module.css. What I want to do is rather than use the default hashed css names that vue provides (.grid becomes ._grid_1a0w7_1), I wanted to setup my own class names so that there is a format something like .grid_grid__XyZ14. Here are the docs for vite's css module options.
I am not sure if this is the right approach to hash a class name, but I keep getting a slash once in a while / and this causes the css rule to not be applied.
Is this the wrong approach to use crypto, or what would be an elegant solution to hashing  a css class name so that something like .grid becomes xYz23 without having to worry about any characters showing up that are not valid in css?
import path from 'path'
import crypto from 'crypto'

defineNuxtConfig({
  vite: {
    css: {
      modules: {
        generateScopedName: (className, filename) => {
          const fileName = path.basename(filename, '.module.css')
          
          const hash = crypto
            .createHash('sha256')
            .update(className)
            .digest('base64')
            .substring(0, 5)

          return `${fileName}_${className}__${hash}`

        }
      }
    }
  }
})

I updated this code to use a recursive function, and had to add a + in the if condition because that character was also being added and causing the css rule to not be applied.
import path from 'path'
import crypto from 'crypto'

defineNuxtConfig({
  vite: {
    css: {
      modules: {
        generateScopedName: (className, filename) => {
          const fileName = path.basename(filename, '.module.css')

          function createHash(hash) {
            const _hash = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(hash).digest('base64').substring(0, 5)

            if (_hash.includes('/') || _hash.includes('+')) {
              return createHash(_hash)
            }

            return _hash
          }

          const hash = createHash(className)

          return `${fileName}_${className}__${hash}`

        }
      }
    }
  }
})


See this answer for an overview of how / and + are legitimate base64 chars.
This could be fixed by removing the if condition and instead adding  appropriate replacements to the end of your existing _hash.
const _hash = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(hash).digest('base64').substring(0, 5) replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_')

The replacements don't have to be these specifically. But don't use anything in the existing base64 alphabet.
However, the encode to base64 is not really useful here. It doesn't help with collision. You could just use the first n chars of the sha256 in hex string form.
const _hash = 
 crypto.createHash('sha256').update(hash).digest('hex').substring(0, 5);

You won't have the + and / problem at all here, since those are not valid hex chars.

I noticed that vercel's site has these hashes with letters and numbers and vue does something similar, is there a different hashing function or method rather than just using node crypto that would be more suitable for css classes?

Under the hood they are probably using sha256 or any other hashing algorithm that uses alphanumeric. So sha256 is common, and absolutely fine. When creating a custom function like yours to rearrange things, its totally reasonable and in line with the usual to use something like node crypto and sha256. Theres no huge difference between the alphanumeric hashing algo's other than possible better collision avoidance. And sha256 is indeed a great choice. The problem you have isn't because of sha256 at all. its because of the base64. Hence using hex output of the sha256 will work perfect.

The link you have in the answer seems to be broken and I couldn't follow it

Oops, fixed now
